# IIS and Apache Content-Type header... IIS will only accept one, Apache accepts more than one

Tags: android, apache, iis, content-type

IIS will send back a 400 error if you send it two content-type headers, here is an example:

> 1: Content-type : application/json
>
> 2: Content-type : application/json; charset=utf-8;

Apache handles that and processes properly for json.

My reading of the w3c spec is that only a single Content-Type header is allowable.  Arguably though both headers mean exactly the same thing as JSON in this case is as I understand it, UTF-8.  So whose right here?  IIS or Apache?

My app fails running on IIS, the Android lib I am using sends 2 headers if I give it my own and fails on IIS.  So currently I'm locked into Apache.

Comment: In my opinion, the IIS is right. Normally, one request will only contain just one Content-type. If your first Content-type is multipart/byteranges, second is application/json, how the server handle this request?

Comment: I don't know enough about apache architecture to know why it allows 2 headers for Content-Type as shown above..  Maybe its smart enough to realize it means the same thing as far as JSON is concerned..  Do not know.

Comment: After a lot of time on this, for vanilla IIS, I think this logic is in HTTP.sys and I was able to find no way to overcome it using handlers, URL Rewrite, or filters.  The easy option is stay on Apache, fix the client code to send only one content-type and then move to IIS if its still a priority.